# CSS custom properties not working in react production build

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, styling

I have several custom css properties defined on the root, and they are working fine on the development build, however they aren't loading on the production build.
The custom properties are defined in index.css.

```
:root {
  --light-theme-background-color: #fafafa;
  --light-theme-text-color: #333;
  --light-theme-active-color: #cbcbcb;
  --dark-theme-background-color: #1d2327;
  --dark-theme-text-color: #227093;
  --dark-theme-active-color: #343434;
}
```

[image]

In the dev tools the custom properties are grayed out and when I hover I get the message that they are not defined.

Comment: Probably you are using some different configuration on development and production. So,  production is getting parsed differently and not in the way you want. Check your package.json and bundler configuration

Comment: The problem is, I don't know how to change any of these.

Comment: If you don't know about these. Then I will suggest learning more about it and then only playing with the configuration.